# Return error message on subprocess exit to VSCode Git

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I'm in the process of implementing a little pre-commit hook that calls gitleaks protect prior to every commit.

This works well in a terminal but when trying to commit from within VSCode, a non-descriptive "Git: O" is returned (I assume this is simply the first line of gitleaks, part of its ascii logo).

As you can tell, I've tried multiple ways to have VSCode's Git module return a proper message upon exit of the submodule. However, nothing seems to work in that regard.

```
def eprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, file=sys.stderr, **kwargs)

exit_code = subprocess.run("gitleaks protect -v --staged -c gitleaks.toml",shell=True)
if exit_code.returncode == 1:
    eprint("This is a test")
    sys.exit("TEST")
```

How do I return an alert window in VSCode that displays a message whenever the subprocess is exiting with exit code 1?

EDIT:

Ok. This works somehow, but it fails in so far as that
`subprocess.run("gitleaks version", shell=True, stdout=dev_null, stderr=dev_null)` only works with my WSL Bash whereas `subprocess.run("gitleaks version", stdout=dev_null, stderr=dev_null)` (without the **shell=True**) only works for my VSCode with Windows Git Bash.

Any way to make this portable, so **FileNotFoundError** is correctly thrown on both systems?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# pylint: disable=C0116,W0613

import sys
import warnings
import subprocess

dev_null = subprocess.DEVNULL

def eprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, file=sys.stderr, **kwargs)

def gitleaks_installed():
    try:
        subprocess.run("gitleaks version", shell=True, stdout=dev_null, stderr=dev_null)
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return False

if gitleaks_installed():
    exit_code = subprocess.run("gitleaks protect -v --staged -c gitleaks.toml", shell=True, stdout=dev_null, stderr=dev_null)
    if exit_code.returncode == 1:
        eprint("gitleaks has detected sensitive information in your changes. Commit aborted.")
        subprocess.run("gitleaks protect -v --staged -c gitleaks.toml", shell=True)
        sys.exit(1)
else:
    eprint("gitleaks is not installed or in the PATH.")
    sys.exit(1)
```

EDIT2: NVM. The `gitleaks_installed` part doesn't work at all under WSL Bash. It either always True or always False, depending on whether I include `shell=True`.

Is there a better way to detect whether gitleaks is installed/in the PATH or not?

Answer (score 0):

The object returned by `subprocess.run` is a CompletedProcess object, not the return code. You have to access its `.returncode` attribute to examine what it returned.

However, you might instead add `check=True` to have Python throw an error on failure.

You should also almost certainly get rid of the superfluous `shell=True` by parsing the command line into tokens yourself.

```
try:
    subprocess.run(
        ["gitleaks", "protect", "-v", "--staged", "-c", "gitleaks.toml"],
        check=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    eprint("gitleaks has detected sensitive information in your changes. Commit aborted.")
    sys.exit(1)
except FileNotFoundError:
    eprint("gitleaks is not installed or in the PATH.")
    sys.exit(1)
```

This also avoids running the process a second time just to obtain the output.  If you want to force your own message to go on top, capture the output and print it after your message (add `capture_output=True` and `text=True`).

You might also want to replace `eprint` with `logging.warn`, and perhaps return different exit codes in the different error scenarios. (Bash conventionally returns 127 when it can't find a binary, but that's just Bash.)

Running `subprocess.run` on a string, instead of a list, without `shell=True` weirdly happens to work on Windows, but my recommendation would be to always avoid trying to exploit that for convenience. Perhaps see also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)

Comment: I'm aware I have to access the `.returncode` attribute.

Comment: I'll check out your solution now.
Thank you.

Comment: I tested your solution. It works fine (I'll probably use <3.6 idioms though. As silly as that sort of backwards compatibility may seem).

Now how do I get access to the original stdout though, after I captured the output?
Since `subprocess.run` is in the try block, I can't access it from the except block.

Comment: I figured it out.

I can do `except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:`
then print via `print(e.output)`.

Comment: Sorry about that and thanks for the comments. You will perhaps want to examine `e.stderr` too, or instead.

Answer (score -1):

Not the most elegant solution, but this works.
Instead of the `FileNotFoundError` exception, we're using the `subprocess.run` returncode.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# pylint: disable=C0116,W0613

import sys
import subprocess

dev_null = subprocess.DEVNULL

def eprint(*args, **kwargs):
    print(*args, file=sys.stderr, **kwargs)

def gitleaks_installed():
    exit_code = subprocess.run("gitleaks version", shell=True, stdout=dev_null, stderr=dev_null)

    if exit_code.returncode == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False

if gitleaks_installed():
    exit_code = subprocess.run("gitleaks protect -v --staged -c gitleaks.toml", shell=True, stdout=dev_null, stderr=dev_null)

    if exit_code.returncode == 1:
        eprint("gitleaks has detected sensitive information in your changes. Commit aborted.")
        subprocess.run("gitleaks protect -v --staged -c gitleaks.toml", shell=True)
        sys.exit(1)
else:
    eprint("gitleaks is not installed or in the PATH.")
    sys.exit(1)
```